# Strapi v4: no relational fields when populating

Tags: javascript, node.js, strapi

I'm trying to populate a specific relation, using the relation name (`categories`) in combination with the populate parameter but it doesn't populate the `categories`.

When I look at my schema, I see that the relational field is present in the attributes object. But I still only get the non-relational fields in my response.

I tried every combination mentioned on the [Strapi documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/developer-resources/database-apis-reference/rest/populating-fields.html#population) but none of them worked.

The `find` permission is also enabled for the content-types that are being populated which in this case is `categories`.

```
/api/products?populate=*
/api/products?populate[0]=categories
/api/products?populate[categories]=*
```

#### My Product schema

```
{
  "kind": "collectionType",
  "collectionName": "products",
  "info": {
    "singularName": "product",
    "pluralName": "products",
    "displayName": "Product",
    "description": ""
  },
  "options": {
    "draftAndPublish": true
  },
  "pluginOptions": {},
  "attributes": {
    "title": {
      "type": "string"
    },
    "images": {
      "type": "media",
      "multiple": true,
      "required": false,
      "allowedTypes": [
        "images"
      ]
    },
    "categories": {
      "type": "relation",
      "relation": "oneToMany",
      "target": "api::category.category"
    }
  }
}
```

#### System

- Strapi version: `4.1.8`
- NPM version: `8.3.2`
- Node.js version: `16.13.2`
- Database: MySQL

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: Other choice is to use [populate deep](https://market.strapi.io/plugins/strapi-plugin-populate-deep) from strapi marketplace, just install, configure the default depth and then on every request where you want deep just add populate: deep

you will have to populate inside your controller, as in [Strapi documentation](https://docs.strapi.io/developer-docs/latest/getting-started/introduction.html)

**Query Engine API: Populating**

```
strapi.db.query('api::article.article').findMany({
 populate: true,
});
```

**Entity Service API: Populating**

```
const entries = await strapi.entityService.findMany('api::article.article', {
  populate: '*',
});
```

**REST API: Population & Field Selection**

```
const qs = require('qs');
const query = qs.stringify({
  fields: ['title', 'body'],
}, {
  encodeValuesOnly: true,
});
```

If you want to populate everything just use populate: '*'

If you want to populate a relation or more use populate: [relationOne, relationTwo]

Comment: thanks! the reason that I don't use query engine and entity service APIs is that they don't return the meta data like pagination. the rest api part also doesn't work as I mentioned.

Comment: I still do not understand how I extend the core controller to use the populate.  Do I add this inside my coreController somehow like `module.exports = createCoreController("api::article.article",{populate: '*',});` within the `src/article/controllers/article.js` file or do I make a custom controller file?  I just want to extend the core actions to populate relations, but I do not know where to do this and I do not see in the documentation.

Answer (score 4):

You need to enable **find** permission on the **product** as well.  You have to set the **find** permission on all the relationships (or sub-tables).

Use the "role" option.

Answer (score -1):

As an **Example** If you want to fetch data from db based on some conditions and  populate one relationship

```js
const transactions = await strapi
        .query("api::transaction.transaction")
        .findMany({
          where: { user: userId },
          populate: { offer: true },
        });
```

here the result
[image]
If you want to populate all relations

```js
const transactions = await strapi
        .query("api::transaction.transaction")
        .findMany({
          where: { user: userId },
          populate: "*",
        });
```

Comment: how do you manage to populate data with a specific locale? for e.g. I want fields status, unit, and offerStatus to be on some other language