# Strapi Nested Components UI, data not visible, issue

Tags: database, user-interface, nested, strapi, invisible

Is there any way to get to see the data in the UI of strapi if the components made are nested till third level so that I can make changes there only and does not have to go to database all the time for data changes.[The image shows a link components wihich has three three files inside it and the component itself is wrapped under a component which is again wrapped into another one and so on...it has the data in it but is not visible in the UI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKkc4.png)

I tried contacting the community but if someone figured out a solution by itslef do help as we are at production level now and this cms is to be used by non-technical people now who has no idea of what Database is...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Strapi v4: no relational fields when populating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72152484/strapi-v4-no-relational-fields-when-populating)

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to add data that is more than 2 levels deep and the only problem you are facing is that you can't see the nested JSON in the API response, I would suggest taking a look at

https://www.npmjs.com/package/strapi-plugin-populate-deep.

After installing it properly, you will just have to use you can use it as follows:

Populate a request with the default max depth.

```
/api/articles?populate=deep
```

Populate a request with the custom depth

```
/api/articles?populate=deep,10
```

Populate a request with the custom depth and filter

```
/api/articles/1?populate=deep,10
```

Comment: Look first thanks for understanding the issue almost correctly, but the thing here is that I can see it in my API response but not able to see in the strapi UI, that is the admin panel that strapi provides, after the second level...... I even attached the Image of the issue to it in the question please do visit .